# Obserable take select conversion

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I am learning RX (Reactive Extensions), I tried to use some code samples from internet, the source code was in C#:

```cs
var input = new[] {1,2,3,4,5,4}.ToObservable();
var output = input.Take(5).Select(x => x * 10);

output.Dump();
```

I want to use F# to do the same thing. I download RX, and create a F# windows application, add reference to System.Reactive. My IDE is VS 2010 Ultimate, RX version is: 1.1.11111 Here is my code:

```
#light
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq

let input = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 4].ToObservable()
let output = input.Take(5).Select(fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
printfn "%A" output
printfn "Done"
```

I believe it is an easy job, however, in my IDE, neither C# nor F# gave any useful information.  Besides, there is no output.Dump() I can use in C# or in F#.
The lambda expression in F# didn't show any information.
The `printfn "%A"` output showed this information:

> System.Reactive.Linq.Observable+SelectObservable`2[System.Int32,Microsoft.FSharp
>   .Core.Unit]

Let me know if I miss something or if my code is wrong.
Thanks and happy new year to you all!

Comment: Your `Select` lambda is wrong -- it's returning `unit`, but you need to return the transformed value instead.

Comment: Hi, ildjarn: I want to see the result: i.e show 1 2 3 4 5 displayed on screen.  If you know how to return the transformed value, please show me your code!

Comment: @JohnJohn : `let output = input.Take(5).Select(fun x -> x * 10)` returns the transformed value...

Comment: Hi, I tried this, there is no meaningful output displayed, just this: System.Reactive.Linq.Observable+SelectObservable`2[System.Int32,Microsoft.FSharp .Core.Unit]

Comment: @JohnJohn : It sounds like your real question is simply how to display the contents of observable containers -- if so, the current question content is very misleading.

Comment: Really, you do NOT need to prefix your titles with tags.  *We have tags*.  And the tag system is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [learn about Observables](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples) more. You have to subscribe to the observable collection. Also you should not make side-effects in `Select` method. So the code should look like this:

```
use xs = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 4].ToObservable().Take(5).Subscribe(printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Hi: Rarous: Thanks! I have figured it out 2 days ago, but I can not answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this, but this produces the result you expect.

```
let input = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 4].ToObservable()
let output = input.Take(5).ToEnumerable()
printfn "%A" output
```

All this does is convert a `#seq<int>` to `IObservable<int>` and back again. I suppose it would be more meaningful if you chained some additional transformations prior to calling `ToEnumerable`.